# Joint distribution as a function of marginal distribution.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be random variables. I would like to keep $X$ fixed but $Y$ varies.

Is it possible to write $E[XY]$ as a function of the distribution $P(Y)?$

For example if $X,Y$ are independent, then I can write 
$$
E[XY] = E[X]E[Y] = E[X]\cdot P(Y)(\mathbb{R} ). 
$$

So, if $Y$ varies we can see this as a function $P(Y) \mapsto E[X] P(Y)(\mathbb{R}).$

What if $X,Y$ are not independent?

Edit: I was trying to give a minimal example, which turns out a bit confusing. Let me the question I had in mind. Let $X,Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be random variables. Let $\phi:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be some measurable function.

Then I want to write
$$
E[\phi(X)Y]
$$
as a function of the distribution of  $P(Y),$ where this is defined
$$
P(Y)(A) = P ( X^{-1}(A) ), \quad A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).
$$

Comment: What exactly do $P(Y)$ and $P(Y)(\mathbb R)$ denote here? We have the distribution $P_Y$ which is a probability measure prescribed by $B\mapsto P(Y\in B)$. But $P_Y(\mathbb R)=1$ and not $\mathbb EY$.

Comment: I added some remarks to the question. Thank you.

Comment: What is the relation between X and Y

Comment: No relation. They are random variables.

Comment: $\mathbb E\phi(X)Y$ is a real number. So actually you want to write a real number as a *function* of a *distribution* (which on its turn is a *function* on sets)...Weird, isn't it? Btw, you defined $P(Y)(A)=P(X^{-1}(A))$ but probably meant $P(Y)(A)=P(Y^{-1}(A))$.